# Relationship between two Poisson Processes

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $\{X(t)\}$ and $\{Y(t)\}$ are independent Poisson processes with parameters $x$ and $y$ respectively.  For any $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq0}$, how can I find $\mathbf{P}(X(t)=m)$ at the time that $Y(t)$ first reaches $n$?

Comment: No, the assumption is that $t$ is the **first** time $Y$ reaches $n$.

Comment: The number $N$ of $X$-events between two successive $Y$-events (counting time zero as a $Y$-event) is geometrically distributed with parameter $p=x/(x+y)$, that is, $P(N=n)=p^n(1-p)$ for every $n\geqslant0$. Thus, at the first time when $Y(t)=n$, $X(t)=N_1+\cdots+N_i$ for some i.i.d. copies $(N_k)$ of $N$. Now, the distribution of $N_1+\cdots+N_i$ is...

Comment: (Doob-Meyer? Great Scot...)

Answer (score 7):

$Z(t) = X(t) + Y(t)$ is a Poisson process with rate $x+y$.  Given such a process, we can realize $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ by assigning each occurrence of the $Z$ process independently to the $X$ or $Y$ process with probabilities $x/(x+y)$ and $y/(x+y)$ respectively.  You're looking for the probability that $X(t) = m$ when $Y(t)$ hits $n$, i.e. that of the 
first $m+n$ occurrences of the $Z$ process, exactly $m$ are assigned to $X$ and $n$ (including the last one) are assigned to $Y$: this is
$${m+n-1 \choose m} \left(\dfrac{x}{x+y}\right)^{m} \left(\dfrac{y}{x+y}\right)^{n}$$

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused.  We don't know what $t$ is.  $t$ itself is a random variable

Comment: The point is that the value of $t$  doesn't matter, just which occurrences of the $Z$ process belong to $X$ and which belong to $Y$.